# How to prevent Oracle accounts from locking due to bad passwords by a particular source?

Tags: oracle

We're having trouble with certain clients repeatedly attempting to logon to important service accounts that they shouldn't be using with old/bad passwords, causing the account to lock(timed) and thus breaking the application that *does* own that account. Due to SOX requirements we are not allowed to remove the `FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` limit or otherwise to circumvent this locking behavior. Therefore **we need to prevent the specific clients in question from making any attempt to logon to particular accounts**. Finding the responsible party and getting them to fix their stuff isn't always easy in a large corporation, so I'd like to find a solution that can be implemented on the database side. But how exactly?

Triggers can make such decisions, but there is no such thing as a `BEFORE LOGON` trigger, and an `AFTER LOGON` trigger would never fire because the bad password prevents the process from achieving logon. Setting `sqlnet.ora` parameters `TCP.EXCLUDED_NODES` and `TCP.VALIDNODE_CHECKING` could prevent connections from a particular source, but that would impact all our databases on that host and all accounts in them, whereas we have to narrowly tailor it to specific accounts on a specific database.

Unlocking the account after it has been locked is trivial (done that already). But unless it's polling constantly almost every second, there will be some time when critical jobs could fail due to the account being locked.

This is a classic Denial-of-Service issue. There has to be way to protect an important account from being disabled in this fashion by a bad client spinning on repeated connection attempts with an old password. It can't be that easy for anyone with a TCP/IP path to the server to break applications simply by spamming an account with a bogus password. Has anyone ever come up with a solution for this?

**Update:**  I found an acceptable solution after thinking on this for a day, provided as an answer below.

Comment: @J.D. That sounds like exactly the *problem*. They are using an old password already, which causes the service account to get locked.

Comment: @pmdba ah yes, brain fart. Cheers! One would think they'd learn after the first time to stop trying to use that account when they're unable to login with it. But perhaps the solution would be to just change the server account itself and not tell the clients the name of the new service account.

Comment: @J.D., if they were humans, yes. But not if it's some scheduled script or something buried in middleware somewhere and nobody's checking logs or it simply keeps retrying on error. In the particular case I'm dealing with now, it's some virtual pod with an untraceable hostname behind a firewall and a NAT IP, with some vague group loosely associated with it saying there are lots of folks with connections set up in some tool we know nothing about. So, finding it nearly impossible to get it shut down from the client side.

Comment: @PaulW Ah, your use of the word "*client*" made me think you meant people / end users. Anyway, see my updated comment. Curious your thoughts on just changing the service accounts themselves?

Comment: @PaulW I don't think there's any other solution to this: you either have to allow unlimited bad logins to prevent denial of service (not allowed under SOX), or you have accept the risk of DoS and respond by manually blocking the offending client. Is the NAT IP specific enough that you can block it? Would use of Audit Vault Database Firewall appliance offer any benefit, if it let you block out specific client *applications*? It wouldn't be a *cheap* solution, but have you looked into that at all?

Comment: @pmdba, no we haven't gotten into a bad enough situation that would warrant purchasing anything or relying on third party software. I expected the answer would be "no" as nothing came to my mind, but was hoping for some new feature introduced in some version in recent years that I didn't notice. Anyway I think it's a small design flaw in Oracle that shouldn't be that hard to fix. Surely it would be feasible to introduce exclusion filters by at least host and username that work pre-(or mid-) authentication. See my update though on another idea.

Answer (score 1):

Option #1:

**Change** the account in question.
Not just the *password* - use an entirely different *account name*.

It should only require a small outage while all the *known* clients are updated with the new credentials and this activity would permanently close the door on this miscreant code entirely.

You **must** have this option in your "Security arsenal" for cases where a system account is compromised by, say, a disgruntled employee.

Option #2:

The systems being compromised must be "of value" to your business.
As such, anything that puts those systems "at risk" puts the business at risk.

Go and get the necessary Management approvals, then block the I.P. Address at the firewall level.

Once you've done that, those ...

> ...folks with connections set up in some tool we know nothing about ...

... will *soon* make themselves known, because their "stuff" won't work any more.

Once you have *that* contact, you (or, better still, *they*) can start tracking down the miscreant application code.

Finally, you can [collectively] find a better way of securing that connection or supplying the credentials that should be used.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I was asking for a technical solution, not a management strategy. And moving the owning app to a new account?? That is far and away the most burdensome action one could take given the complexity of the application/middleware constellation that is around some large databases. That interruption and headache that would cause is orders of magnitude worse than the occasional locking. And as soon as you do, those bad actors can simply repoint to the new account and end up hitting it with a bad password, too.

Comment: This tells me that you have credentials stored in too many places (which is probably unavoidable) and without the means to manage them sensibly.  A compromised account is a liability (a.k.a. reportable Data Breach) and you must retain the ability to replace it.  Surely a planned, controlled, [hopefully] one-off correction of the root cause is better than just reacting to any number of "random", unplanned outages?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this for a day, I'm answering my own question because I came upon an idea for an acceptable technique and successfully tested it.

Until Oracle gives us a `BEFORE LOGON` trigger option, it is not possible to tailor the *initial* locking behavior by client/machine or any other attribute other than user (by virtue of the profile assigned). However, it is possible to *immediately* unlock the account in under 1 second after it locks based on the client/machine (or any other attribute) without writing a polling mechanism by means of an `AFTER SERVERERROR` trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SERVERERROR
AFTER SERVERERROR
ON DATABASE
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  var_status varchar2(100);
  var_username varchar2(128);
  var_machine varchar2(100);
  var_error number;
BEGIN
  var_username := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY');
  var_machine := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST');
  var_error := server_error(1);
  
  IF var_username = 'IMPORTANTUSER' AND 
     var_machine = 'abusivemachine' AND -- check for specific client machine triggering this lock
     var_error = 1017 -- bad password
  THEN
    SELECT MAX(account_status)
      INTO var_status
      FROM dba_users
     WHERE username = var_username;
    
    IF var_status LIKE '%LOCKED%' -- the only way the status can be locked and the error code 1017 is if this connection attempt just locked the accuont
    THEN
      dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => 'UNLOCK_ACCOUNT',
                                job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                                job_action => '
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''ALTER USER "'||var_username||'" ACCOUNT UNLOCK''; 
END;
',
                                enabled => TRUE,
                                auto_drop => TRUE,
                                start_date => localtimestamp);
      COMMIT;      
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Obviously the above can be written to be table-driven and more flexible, but this demonstrates the solution.

The trigger intercepts the `ORA-01017: invalid username/password` error being thrown to the client and interrogates the status of the account being hit with a bad password (`AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY` is the only way to get the requested username for a session not yet successfully logged in). On exceeding the profile limit of invalid password attempts, the last attempt will change the status to locked and this trigger can see that. Given that further connection attempts would throw a different error, the combination of the error being `ORA-01017: invalid username/password` and the status being `'%LOCKED%'` can only mean that the current session is the session that *caused* the account to lock (all subsequent attempts would get `ORA-28000: The account is locked`).

Action can then be taken to unlock the account immediately if this is a known issue and an immediate unlock is determined desirable and permissible. Understandably, Oracle does not permit DDL in the context of a system trigger, but by submitting the unlock code to `dbms_scheduler` for immediate execution, assuming the job engine is working properly and there are sufficient job processes, the account is unlocked *almost immediately*. Testing 50 iterations of the locking cycle showed that in all cases the account got unlocked within 1 second of being locked, and **the median delay was only 0.25 seconds**. A sub-second window between locking and unlocking isn't as good as preventing the locking in the first place, but it's a lot better than a home-brew polling mechanism.

Plus, specific action can be taken not merely by account status (the only thing available to a polling mechanism), but selectively by the source of the locking (a particular machine, or program, or IP address, etc..), so that a known abusive source can be immediately reacted to while allowing the normal locking behavior for all other sources. This tailors the unlocking as narrowly as possible, thus limiting the degree to which we are creating a hole in this security measure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Proxy Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#CHDDDHIJ) feature, Tim Hall, for example, [has described](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/proxy-users-and-connect-through) exactly your case:

> You have multiple developers working in a shared schema. Letting multiple people share the same credentials represents a security risk. Instead you create a separate proxy user for each individual, allowing them to connect to the schema owner with their own credentials. If a user leaves a project, you simply lock or drop their user, and they no longer have access to the shared schema.

Comment: That isn't the same situation. The accounts I'm dealing with are not schema owners, but connect accounts used by applications, so we already have separation of object ownership and authentication. Using proxy gives elevated rights (owner privs) and therefore a less secure solution that simply using dedicated connect accounts that have select+DML but no DDL ability. Lastly, this is a management strategy that requires a massive amount of application coding changes across the constellation of apps rather than a tailored technical solution that can be implemented immediately by our DBA team.